# Does octopus eye presents the equivalent of fovea in primates?

Tags: zoology, human-eye, visual-system

I'm working on a simple computational model of Primate eye:  as we know, it presents a central part, the fovea, that is very rich of receptors in comparison with eye periphery. I'm wondering if other species eye, like octopus, present a similar structure: a central fovea. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do have an area of densely packed receptors, although not point-like as the human fovea.

Talbot and Marshall (2011) performed a retinal topography analysis in three species of cephalopods: a cuttlefish, a squid and an octopus.

According to the authors:

> It was found that all species possessed an increase in photoreceptor density in a horizontal streak approximately placed at the position of a potential horizon in the habitat.

Here is an image from the same paper:

[image]

<sup>The retinal topography of each of the three species in this study: (a) *S. plangon* and (b) *O. cyanea* show a prominent, horizontally orientated band of increased photoreceptor density across the horizontal equator of the retina; (c) *S. lessoniana* shows a more centrally positioned area of increased photoreceptor density.</sup>

---

Source: [Talbot, C. and Marshall, J. (2011). The retinal topography of three species of coleoid cephalopod: significance for perception of polarized light. Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society B: Biological Sciences, 366(1565), pp.724-733.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3049017/)